# Find the sum of a convergent series using a well-known function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this series in my calculus book: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{5^nn}$$
The directions are in the title of this question, but I can't think of any functions whose power series looks anything like that when evaluated at a point. Hints are appreciated, because I like to work these out on my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^n}n$$

Answer (score 3):

From Did's solution, we have

$$\log(1+x)=-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(-x)^n}n=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}n$$

Setting $x=1/5$, we obtain:

$$\log(6/5)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{5^n n}$$

Comment: Quote: "Hints are appreciated, because I like to work these out on my own."

Comment: @Did, I do not mean to steal the thunder from you.  But I did see that there is sign mistake in yngabl's solution when compared to the result I got from Mathematica 7.0. So I thought that it might be better to present the right result.

Comment: Your comment is mistaken: you are stealing something from the OP (the right "to work these out on (their) own", as they took care to put it), nothing from me. Additionally, reacting to a misprint in an answer by posting one's own answer instantaneously is rather peculiar, if you ask me (comments are made for this kind of situation).

Comment: @Did, Thanks for the detailed comment.  I just found out the phrase "Hints are appreciated, because I like to work these out on my own" from OP. I did not read it carefully the first time. And next time, I will use the comment part to raise  questions if there are any misprints. Best regards